# Splitting polygon in half.

Tags: calculus, geometry, functions, continuity

Let $P$ be a convex polygon in the plane. Prove that there is a vertical line
which splits P onto two polygons of equal area.

I tried to use intermediate value theorem with no luck.

Comment: It is easy to construct a concave polygon for which the vertical line cuts it into more than two pieces.

Comment: @Michael Right, even if it wasn't vertical, it's still ill-defined if it's the whole line. This is really unclear.

Comment: How do you define "polygon" and "vertical" for this problem? Is the "plane" the Cartesian plane with coordinates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $l_t$ be the horizontal line $y=t$. Now let $P$ denote the points on and inside the polygon.

$$A(t)=\{(x,y)\in P: y\le t\}$$ and 
$$B(t)=\{(x,y)\in P: y\ge t \}.$$

Finally let
$$d(t)=\text{Area }A(t)-\text{Area }B(t)$$.

You can apply Intermediate Value Theorem to $d(t)$.